# <kbd> not working anymore?

Tags: support, comments, kbd

I had that some days ago (I removed the tags then), now I see that from someone else: [Configure OpenSSH server not to require password *or* key for a particular user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204327/configure-openssh-server-not-to-require-password-or-key-for-a-particular-user) 4th comment to the question.

Comment: Ok, I didn't scroll down enough to find the duplicate. How can I close it?

Comment: It's already closed (as a duplicate). There's nothing you need do. Duplicates are not, in and of themselves, bad; they can offer new search paths to the canonical content.

Answer (score 7):

HTML tags, including `<kbd>`, have never worked in comments. Comments only support a small subset of Markdown, namely **bold**, *Italics*, `inline code`, and [links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).